How to fix the vulnerabilities CWE 200 and CWE 287?
I'm checking the frontend side from a project, which was checked by Fortify, and it was resent with some vulnerabilities. In particular, these CRITICAL vulnerabilities were CWE - 200 and CWE - 287.
Here are some articles related to that
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/200.html
https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/287.html
I'm a bit new to frontend development so I'm not very sure how to correct these vulnerabilities. To be specific, these alerts appear, according to the document that I receive, in one HTML file in a line related to the input of the password in the login of my Web Application:
Line in question:
<input matInput type="password" formControlName="contrasena" autocomplete="off">


Part of the code:
 <div class="fila-form-field">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="full-width-input">
            <mat-label i18n="@@logueo_labelContrasena2">Contrase&ntilde;a</mat-label>
            <input matInput type="password" formControlName="contrasena" autocomplete="off">
            <mat-error *ngIf="logueoForm.controls['contrasena'].hasError('required')" i18n="@@logueo_errorSinContrasena">
              Por favor ingrese una contrase&ntilde;a </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="logueoForm.controls['contrasena'].hasError('caracteresProhibidos')" i18n="@@logueo_errorCaractInvalContrasena">
              Se ingresaron caracteres inv&aacute;lidos!</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>

So I was trying to get some research but I still don't get the solution to fix them.
Any solutions?
PS: My application is developed using Angular 16, so the main code is in TypeScript
Solutions, and options to fix or reduce CWE 200 and CWE 287 vulnerabilities
